# ajax asp.net and jquery conflict

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, ajax

I have multiple jquery files in my project.
Yesterday googled this problem and find solution. I edited this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

with this

```
function pageLoad() {
```

Now problem is that if i will  use this in all my jquery files. Every scripts will stops working.

Comment: How do you know there is a conflict? What errors are coming out the javascript console?

Comment: I have jquery slide show when. Im using ajax in asp.net when i press button slide show is going hidden(stops working) This is error : Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a jQuery conflict. Take a look at firebug network traffic, it sounds like something is being requested that isn't returning correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is two different things. The

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

is from and to jquery, it tells when the DOM is loaded and it start executing the code inside.

The

```
function pageLoad() {
```

is from ASP.NET and it is one of handler of Application.Load (client-side)

The reason why it will stop working is because in the same page you can only have one event with the same name, by default pageLoad will be the handler of Application.Load but you can associate another name. I don't see why you have problems between the two, can you explain it better?

EDIT:
After your comment, if you want/need to use Sys.Application.add_load (by default pageLoad) you should add a different name for each js file you need.

From msdn:

```
// Attach a handler to the load event.
Sys.Application.add_load(applicationLoadHandler);

function applicationLoadHandler() {
    // Redirect to alternate page if not business hours.
    var d = new Date();
    if (!(8 < d.getHours() < 17)) {
        window.location = "AfterHours.aspx";
    }
```

As you can see, you can give a different name to add_load and you should give a different name to use more than one for the same page/request.

}

Comment: pageLoad works great with only one jquery script file. If I will update in two jquery files with pageLoad. Both stops working.Im using ajax in asp.net when i press button slide show is going hidden(stops working)

Comment: thank you. I dont know how to use it can you show me the way or some tutorials?

Comment: I don't find any good tutorial, you can search for Sys.Application.add_load in google.
Basically you need to use
Sys.Application.add_load(Name_Of_Event);

And instead of pageLoad use the Name_Of_Event.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `pageLoad` with something like this:

```
$(function() {
    // This will be executed when the page is loaded
});
```

or to avoid name collisions...

```
(function($) {
    // This will be executed when the page is loaded
})(jQuery);
```

**Edit**: As rich.okelly pointed out the second example will run as soon as the script is loaded.

Comment: Your second example will be executed as soon as the script is loaded, not when the page has finished loading.

Comment: Thanks mdm For replay. I tried both of them but did not helped me